# DataGridCell Content Disappears When Tooltip Displays

Tags: wpf

I can't seem to bind a ToolTip to the DataGridCell's content without having the content in the cell disappear.  In other words, when I mouse over the cell the tooltip appears as expected but the cells content is no longer visible (permanently unless I scroll down the list and back up).  Bellow is the WPF I'm having trouble with:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content, Mode=OneWay}"> 
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

What can I do to stop the DataGridCell's content from disappearing when the ToolTip displays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind to `Content` property, which can be many things, but mainly it`s some control: `TextBlock` for text, `CheckBox` for bool data and so on. This controls are already children of other visual element so their disappearance may be because they are removed from cell and added to `ToolTip`. If it is the case then it`s done somewhere in your code I guess and you have to handle this, but that is not a good solution.

Alternatively you can add a converter to the binding that will parse `Content` and extract the value, but that solution is not so good too.

Better way to handle this is to bind to actual source, not it`s visual representation. If you do not create columns automatically, then you can define tooltip style for every column:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
          <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
              <Style>
                  <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
              </Style>
           </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
       </DataGridTextColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this more generic for a template? I.e. I have a template with a key "DataGridCellWithToolTip" that has the following setter and I have the same issue as above                                           
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"/>

Comment: @Thatoneguy, well, if you want a single Style for this you can add a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your Binding, which will extract values from controls and return them as text. I can't think of other generic approach here.